# VB.NET - Set windows to control/manage wireless over third-party clients

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, wireless

Within VB.NET, trying to find an easy way to in a sense check the check-box "Use Windows to configure my Wireless Network Settings". This is an option that forces windows to use your wireless over third-party programs that may try to steal control. I am aware this requires to have WZC enabled within services and that's something that can be easily accomplished one way or another.

I doubt or rather cannot find a proper registry value or API call to check or initiate such a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a registry-recorder to record the changes when manually changing the value, then its a piece of cake to implement the register change in code.

There are plenty programs that can be used to see what changes has been done in the registry, here are one free: http://www.kephyr.com/systemsherlocklite/index.phtml, but google may find more or better variants out there.

With this tool, create a registry dump:

```
 systemsherlock.exe -dump d1.dat -regdirs HKEY_ROOT
```

Do the change in the wireless network settings
Do a new dump of the registry:

```
 systemsherlock.exe -dump d2.dat -regdirs HKEY_ROOT
```

And last, compare them and see what has changed:

```
systemsherlock.exe -compare d1.dat d2.dat
```